# How can I schedule the submit of form depending upon a variable?

Tags: php, forms, action

```
<form action="<?php if($count==3) 
                        echo"populate3.php"; 
                    else
                        echo"populate1.php"; ?>" method="get" id="form1">
```

Is this correct to write ?
What could be alternatives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$action="":
 if($count==3) 
 {
 $action="populate3.php";      
 }
else
{
 $action="populate1.php"; 
}

echo ("<form action=\"$action\" method=\"get\" id=\"form1\">");
```